# Boost Directed Graph - add_edge - stored_edge_property

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-graph, directed-graph

```
    typedef  boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, NodeInfo, EdgeInfo> Graph;

   Graph g(10);
   EdgeInfo be;
   add_edge(0,1,be,g);
```

Error:
 use of deleted function 'boost::detail::stored_edge_property

Changing "undirected" to "directed" causes error under linux (gcc/4.9.2) while compiles fine on windows visual studio express 2013. Boost: 1.59.0.

The culprit seems to be add_edge

Is there a quick fix?

Some forums have pointed to BGL incompatibilities with C++11 asking coders to revert to C++03. Is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem:

- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru: gcc 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8a6a5c6dd6562dd)</kbd>**
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru: gcc 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c642a193ec39e730)</kbd>**
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru: gcc 5.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d855b9daf6c06872)</kbd>**
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru: gcc 5.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d855b9daf6c06872)</kbd>**
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru: clang 3.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fc8533bced9523b)</kbd>**

With the following graphs:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct NodeInfo { };
struct EdgeInfo { };

int main() {
    using namespace boost;
    {
        typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, NodeInfo, EdgeInfo> Graph;
        Graph g(10);
    }
    {
        typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, NodeInfo, EdgeInfo> Graph;
        Graph g(10);
    }
}
```

This tells me your problem is likely with the NodeInfo/EngeInfo types. If they are not copyable etc. this could lead to errors. MSVC might be more lenient than the standard requires (they frequently are in areas of name lookup and reference binding).

Comment: thanks @sehe. add_edge is raising the error. What is the fix like?

Comment: oops - not even add_edge - still hunting for the bug

Comment: Don't hunt for the bug. Hunt for the cause of your compiler error. It's not unlikely you're doing something to cause the error

Comment: Unused explicit destructor inside NodeInfo had to be removed

Comment: Or you could just declare `= default` the other special member :) Very good job finding it yourself